# Is it possible to see if a library is loaded after another one?

Tags: load

I am trying to find out if a library has been loaded after another one. For example has the ox-bibtex library been loaded after the org-ref library. I know you can look at `fboundp`, `featurep`, but I need to know the order of loading.

I thought I coudl use something like `(seq-position obarray 'org-ref-command)` but obarray seems to have symbols that are not even loaded.

The reason for this is in this case, the second library is clobbering something in the first library, and I am looking for a way to see what order things have been loaded.

Comment: If library A is clobbering something that only exists in library B, doesn't that prove that A was loaded after B?

Comment: It isn't that straightforward I think. library B is redefining an org-mode link, but this sometimes also shows up that a function name is redefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify the file of an already loaded feature, independently on how the file was loaded?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62243/how-to-identify-the-file-of-an-already-loaded-feature-independently-on-how-the)

Comment: @Drew I don't think that answers the question. I need the order they were loaded, not if they were loaded. The functions in that interesting answer show how to find the file it was loaded from I think. What I need is the positions of those files in the load-history.

Comment: Ok, it's not exactly the same question. It's the same answer, however - the load history is a history, so it tells you both whether and when, showing what's loaded just before and just after. The general question that covers both is something like, "How can I tell whether or when a given library was loaded?" Maybe Someone (TM) will change the original question into a general Q &A...

Answer (score 4):

I remembered `load-history`with that, I came up with this that seems to work. Libraries that are loaded more recently have a smaller position (i.e. closer to the beginning of the list).

```
(let ((org-ref-i (seq-position load-history (assoc (locate-library "org-ref") load-history)) )
      (ox-bibtex-i (seq-position load-history (assoc (locate-library "ox-bibtex") load-history))))
  (and org-ref-i ox-bibtex-i
       (> org-ref-i ox-bibtex-i)))
```